# systemd-boot not asking for password?

Tags: btrfs, systemd-boot

I run Arco linux, boot with systemd-boot on an LUKS encrypted btrfs root partition drive but it never ask me for a password for the root drive on boot. Not good.

Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 1):

Acro Linux is based on Arch Linux. You have to use [`systemd-boot-password`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/systemd-boot-password) from Aur. Documented on Arch Linux wiki: [Kernel parameters editor with password protection](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-boot#Kernel_parameters_editor_with_password_protection)

Comment: Package fails to build

Comment: pkg still fails to build after several attempts